# Sharing Registry Space across Multiple Clusters in WSO2

Tags: registry, wso2, cluster-computing, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

By using this [guide](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/deployment_guide.html), I have accomplished to establish a cluster of Carbon products, and change configuration of individual nodes by changing deployment in _system/xxxConfig which is under resources in G-Reg(Governance Registry).

On the other hand, I want to take this case one step further, I need a central G-Reg which shares registry space across other G-Regs (This G-Reg share its registry with the individual Carbon products). Consider such as an deployment:

Suppose we have 5 clusters:

1-Cluster of DSSs with a G-Reg (Sharing Registry)

2-Cluster of DSSs with a G-Reg (Sharing Registry)

3-Cluster of ESBs with a G-Reg (Sharing Registry)

4-Cluster of ESBs with a G-Reg (Sharing Registry)

5-Cluster of ASs with a G-Reg (Sharing Registry)

What I want to achieve is to connect all G-Regs above to a central G-Reg, and control all configuration from there.

Is such a deployment possible with Carbon products, if yes, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. this type of a deployment is possible with GReg..

As you may know already - GReg has a separation of registries..

- Local registry    : Holds the resources specific to a given node
- Config registry   : Holds the resources related to all the nodes in a given cluster
- Governance registry : Holds the resources shared across multiple clusters..

In your deployment you can have 5 config registries for 5 different clusters, mounted on the same central Registry - and have a single Governance registry for shared resources between clusters...

Comment: As long as I understand you propose to deploy one G-Reg at total, am I correct?

Comment: In fact you need not to have an instance of GReg running - because you are making the remote registry calls via JDBC. So - you only need the database.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of this parameter in the reference:  <remoteInstance url="https://x.x.x.x:9443/registry">

Comment: You need not to have a physical registry running the URL - its unique identifier used internally...

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [1] to have a clear understanding about this scenario

[1] http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances/